# Javafx background image using scene builder

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am working on a chatbot project in java and for the GUI I am using JavaFX, and IDE eclipse oxygen and scene builder 8.4.1.

I am having a problem adding a background image to a text area. here is a screen shot of what I did and it just shows nothing(not even an error).

[image]

following is the fxml code generated by scene builder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="51.0" fitWidth="79.0" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="20.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../../../Downloads/background.jpg" />
               </image></ImageView>
            <Label layoutX="118.0" layoutY="36.0" text="Ibot" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </top>
   <center>
      <TextArea editable="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;../../../Downloads/background.jpg&quot;); -fx-background-repeat: stretch;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <HBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <TextField prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="476.0" promptText="Type in here" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </HBox.margin>
            </TextField>
            <Region prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="60.0" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="57.0" text="Send">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not working because as specify in [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textarea) the TextArea is a association of two substructure: a ScrollPane and a Region. You have to change the style of those.

In CSS this should work:

```
#text-area-id .content{
    -fx-background-image : url("the_path_to_your_image")
    /* others properties */
}
```

**Edit to answer comment:**

For a button you just need to set the property `-fx-background-image`:

```
 #your-button{
        -fx-background-image : url("the_path_to_your_image")
 }
```

Comment: I read somewhere that i can add background image to a button also.. Can i do this the same way as u said above?

Comment: You can do it with css but you don't need to do it the same way, there is no native substructure, i edited my answer.

Comment: just one last thing.. I am making a chatbot so interface should be like of chat app. So to display the bot reply and user input, i am using a text area so is there any method to add text at the end of the pre existing text or do i have to get all the text in text area in a string, concat new text than re write the text area again.. Any suggestion?

Comment: For a Textarea there is no any other solution that i know of. But may be it's not the best tool for that, you could try with a customized ListView or TableView.